# Leaflet Draw - How to remove the default toolbar so I can implement a customized one

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm very confused... If I pass draw: false.  I get a toolbar.  I need to customize this toolbar so I passed in the parameters to ensure only imperial units were being used at the time and well.  Now I have 2 toolbars.  How to disable the defualt one?

Answer (score 0):

Had drawControl: true when initializing the map.  That was the issue.